# How many solutions $X^{10} - I=0$ has in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How many solutions $X^{10} - I=0$ has in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$? Where $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of $2 \times 2$ real matrices.

I absolutely have no idea of where I should start from. $I$ and $-I$ solve the equation, but are there any other non-trivial solutions? Are there infinitely many solutions?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist: I've already considered Cayley-Hamilton theorem in my mind, but I don't know how I should apply it to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Answer : infinitely many. Any matrix whose eigenvalues are $1$ and
$-1$ does the job, for example ; you can take

$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 2y+1 & -2 \\ 2y(1+y) & -(2y+1) \end{pmatrix}
$$

All those $A$ satisfy $A^2=I$. There are other solutions ...

Answer (score 3):

There's a way to write all those matrices:

we know that a matrix $X$ satisfying those conditions must be diagonalizable in $\mathbb{C}$, and his minimal polynomial $q_X(t)$ must be real.

If $q_X(t)$ has degree one, then $X=cI$, where $c$ is either $1$ or $-1$, since they are the only solutions to $x^{10}=1$ in the real numbers.

If $q_X(t)$ has degree $2$, it must be 
$$q_X(t)=(x-1)(x+1) \quad or \quad q_X(t)=(x-z_{10})(x-\overline{z_{10}})$$
with $z_{10}$ a $10$-th complex root of $1$.

$X$ solves $X^{10}=I$, if and only if for every $M$ invertible matrix $MXM^{-1}$ solves it. This means that all the solutions are the real matrices diagonalizable with eigenvalues
$$
(1,1)\quad (1,-1)\quad (-1,-1)\quad (\overline{z_{10}},z_{10}) 
$$

You can also write these as the matrices similar to

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}
\quad or \quad
\begin{pmatrix} \cos\big(n\frac{2\pi}{10}\big) & \sin\big(n\frac{2\pi}{10}\big) \\ -\sin\big(n\frac{2\pi}{10}\big) & \cos\big(n\frac{2\pi}{10}\big) \end{pmatrix}
$$
for some integer $n$.

For example, the matrices
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & s \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
are similar to the first one, for all $s$ real, so you have an infinite set of matricial solutions to your equation.

Comment: To make this answer more fitting to the question, note that there are infinitely many solutions to the stated problem (which fall into the classes you've listed).

Comment: Also, note that a $5$th root of unity would work here as well.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom 5th root? Among the 10th ones there are all of them..

Comment: Whoops, right.  Never mind then

Answer (score 0):

Let $A \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ be such that $A^{2}=I$. Then of course $A^{10}-I=0$.

One such matrix is 
$
D=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}
$

Then all matrices of the form $A=PDP^{-1}$ satisfy $A^{2}=I$.

So, there are infinitely many solutions for $X^{10}-I=0$.

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $A$ does not necessarily have degree 1 or 2. For example, $A$ could be rotation by $36^\circ$, and its minimal polynomial would be $x^{10}-1$.

Comment: Ah, I see. But the minimal polynomial doesn't have to be one of the ones you listed, it could be the product any two complex degree one factors of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ or $x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1$ corresponding to conjugate roots. The minimal polynomial of $36^\circ$ rotation is $(x-\omega)(x-\overline{\omega})=x^2-2\cos(\pi/5)x+1$, where $\omega=\cos(\pi/5)+i\sin(\pi/5)$.

Answer (score 0):

In a non-commutative setting any polynomial equation is likely to be infinitely many solutions. Indeed, if $A$ is, say, an $\Bbb R$-algebra and $a\in A$ satisfies the polinomial relation
$$
P(a)=0
$$
for some polynomial $P(x)\in\Bbb R[x]$ then for any invertible $g\in A$ the element $a^\prime=gag^{-1}$ will also satisfy
$$
P(a^\prime)=0.
$$
This is certainly the case for a ring of matrices, unless $a$ is a scalar matrix (which satisfies a degree 1 polynomial relation), i.e. a central element.

Answer (score 0):

If we choose a $X$ such that $X^{10}=I_2$ then it is a solution.

So let $X=\begin{pmatrix}0&a\\\frac{1}{a}&0\end{pmatrix}$ for any arbitrary $a\in\mathbb{R}$. There are infinite solutions.